# Get a particular column value count in oracle with inner join

Tags: oracle

I am having 2 tables by joining both i am getting some columns and values

```
 Select                  
    tbl_orderdetails.category_name,
    tbl_orderdetails.branch_name,
    tbl_ordermaster.created_date,
    tbl_ordermaster.user_id, 
    tbl_orderdetails.order_details_id,
    tbl_orderdetails.branch_id 
 From tbl_orderdetails Inner Join tbl_ordermaster ON 
    tbl_orderdetails.order_master_id=tbl_ordermaster.ordermasterid 
 where tbl_ordermaster.user_id='12'
```

I want to get number of times a particular branch name came.I used count but its not working and i want only max number of times the branch name came and top 3 to be displayed .
Eg:

```
vellore=100,
chennai=18,
tvl=80,
harithuwar=90
```

It should display only

```
vellore
harithwar 
tvl
```

sample data
orderdetails

### orderdatailsid | order_master_id |branchname| category| branchid

### 1   |   112 |   vellore |   nad |   123

### 2   |   112 |   vellore |   hu  |   123

### 3   |   113 |   chennai |   ji  |   121

### 4   |   112 |   vellore |   hi  |   123

### 5   |   134 |   tvl |   ui  |   145

### 6   |   134     |   tvl |   jo  |   145

masterdetails

### ordermasterid  |  userid

### 112        |      12

### 113 |    13

### 134  |        14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT T.*,S.* FROM
(
  Select TD.category_name,TD.branch_name,TM.created_date,TM.user_id,TD.order_details_id,TD.branch_id
  From tbl_orderdetails TD Inner Join tbl_ordermaster TM ON 
    TD.order_master_id = TM.ordermasterid 
  Where TM.user_id='12'
) T Left Join
(
  Select T1.branch_name,Count(T1.branch_name) As No_Of_Branch
  From tbl_orderdetails T1 Inner Join tbl_ordermaster T2 ON 
       T1.order_master_id = T2.ordermasterid 
  Where T2.user_id='12'
  Group By T1.branch_name
) S On S.branch_name = T.branch_name
```

**Update**

If you want to get `Max` of `count`

Try this

```
SELECT T.*,S.* FROM
(
  Select TD.category_name,TD.branch_name,TM.created_date,TM.user_id,TD.order_details_id,TD.branch_id
  From tbl_orderdetails TD Inner Join tbl_ordermaster TM ON 
    TD.order_master_id = TM.ordermasterid 
  Where TM.user_id='12'
) T Inner Join
(
SELECT M.branch_name,Max(M.No_Of_Branch) FROM
  (
    Select T1.branch_name,Count(T1.branch_name) As No_Of_Branch
    From tbl_orderdetails T1 Inner Join tbl_ordermaster T2 ON 
         T1.order_master_id = T2.ordermasterid 
    Where T2.user_id='12'
    Group By T1.branch_name
  ) M Group By M.branch_name
) S On S.branch_name = T.branch_name
```

Comment: whats that T.* and S.* ?

Comment: Here you joining Two queries one is from T and another one is from S

Comment: ORA-00904: "T"."BRANCH_NAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 24 got error like this when i tried to execute

Comment: still i am getting error like this ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 10

Comment: @NandhiniDevi I forgot to add `group by` clause. Can you please check now

Comment: i want to get highest number of times a particular branch occurs in the same code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56011/discussion-between-nandhini-devi-and-vignesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Count is working good below the Examples,

```
create table orderdetails(orderdatailsid number, order_master_id number,branchname varchar(20), category varchar(20), branchid number);
insert into orderdetails values (1 , 112 ,'vellore','nad', 123);
insert into orderdetails values (2 , 112 ,'vellore','hu', 123);
insert into orderdetails values (3 , 113 , 'chennai','ji', 121);
insert into orderdetails values (4 , 112 , 'vellore' ,'hi', 123);
insert into orderdetails values (5 , 134 , 'tvl','ui', 145);
insert into orderdetails values (6 , 134 , 'tvl','jo', 145);
insert into orderdetails values (7 , 113 , 'chennai','ji', 121);
insert into orderdetails values (8 , 112 , 'vellore','hi', 123);
insert into orderdetails values (9 , 134 , 'tvl','ui', 145);
```

**select * from orderdetails;**

```
create table masterdetails(ordermasterid number, userid number);
insert into masterdetails values(112 , 12);
insert into masterdetails values(113 , 13);
insert into masterdetails values(134 ,14);
```

**select * from masterdetails;**

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT orderdetails.branchname, count(*)   as Cout          
            From orderdetails left Join masterdetails ON 
            orderdetails.order_master_id=masterdetails.ordermasterid 
            group by orderdetails.branchname
            order by cout desc
            ) WHERE ROWNUM <4;
```